# Littlewood's First Principle.

Tags: real-analysis

Does anyone have a good proof of Littlewood's first principle?

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite measure, and let $\epsilon > 0$. Can anyone provide a rigorous proof that there is an open set $O$ which is the union of a *finite* number of pairwise disjoint open bounded intervals such that $m(O \setminus E) + m(E \setminus O) < \epsilon$.

Any references or answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/66803/8271) for some thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

There is a proof in [this PDF](http://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2011/littlewood-a4.pdf).

Comment: But in that PDF the intervals are not disjoint.

Comment: @Twink: It’s straightforward to prove that any union of finitely many open intervals is the union of finitely many pairwise disjoint open intervals, namely, its connected components.