# Disproving Littlewood's first principle

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Im trying to disprove the principle for $\epsilon = 0$ so need to get measure of $(E\setminus G) \cup (G\setminus E)$ equal to $0$. Any suggestions for the counterexample?

Comment: [Littlewood's first principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144419/littlewoods-first-principle), and [a proof](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/tma4225/2011/littlewood-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

So, you want a set $E\subset\mathbb  R$ of finite measure for which there is **no**   open set $O$ which is the finite union of  disjoint open   intervals such that $m(O\triangle  E)=0$.

Let $E$ be a ["Fat" Cantor Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287866/). If $O$ is nonempty, $O\setminus E$ contains an interval. If $O$ is empty, $E\setminus O$ has positive measure.