# Prove that a measurable set with finite measeure is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Show that if $E$ has finite measure and $\epsilon>0$, then $E$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets, each of which has measure at most $\epsilon$.

Any hints or ideas would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure is the disjoint union of a finite number of measurable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18829/every-subset-of-mathbbr-with-finite-measure-is-the-disjoint-union-of-a-fini)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove that there exists $M>0$ such that $m(E\setminus[-M,M])<\varepsilon$, and then break up $E\cap[-M,M]$ into small pieces.

Comment: How to break up a set into small pieces? That's what the problem is about, so I don't know if I can do that with set $E \cap [-M,M]$.

Comment: @antihappiness:  E.g., $E\cap[a,a+\varepsilon)$ has measure at most $\varepsilon$.  For bounded sets you will have no problem breaking up the set in this way.

Comment: Ok, now, to find $M$, if $E=\Bbb Q$ (for example) then any $M$ works, because $\Bbb Q$ has measure zero. If $E$ is bounded, we can take $M=\max\{|\sup E|, |\inf E|\}-\epsilon/2$ (right?) but I don't know what will be $M$ in the general case :S is there one or I have to do it by cases?

Comment: @anti-happiness: The bounded monotone sequence $(m(E\cap[-n,n]))_{n=1}^\infty$ has a limit which you can show to be $m(E)$, hence for sufficiently large $n$, $m(E\setminus[-n,n])=m(E)-m(E\cap[-n,n])<\varepsilon$.  Or use $m(E)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}m(E\cap\{x:n-1\leq |x|\leq n\})$, and by convergence of the series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}m(E\setminus[-k,k])=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty m(E\cap\{x:n-1\leq|x|\leq n\})=0$.